# On removable singularities around an specific point

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Learning about singularities, just to be sure that I grasp the content correctly I will ask the following.

Find the radius of convergence of the following function.

$$
\frac{cosz}{z^2-\pi^2/4},
$$

about $z=0$.

Since about $z=0$, the power series of the denominator is just a geometric series, then the singularities are removable, right? The radius of convergence is then infinite.

On the other hand, if I expand for example around $4$, then the singularities become poles, right? In this case the radius of convergence should be $3$??

Why a function can be analytic on different domains depending on where we decide to expand it? Is not counterintuitive?

Comment: Whether or not a function has removable singularities is independent of its series representation. Could you please clarify: 1. How the geometric series (about $z = 0$) has infinite radius (if that's what you're claiming), 2. How (expanded about $z = 4$) the singularities become poles, and 3. How you deduce the radius is $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: I am using the Laurent series for every case. Around zero the denominators has ordinary power series, so there are no terms of the form $1/z^k$, $k\ge1$. From this, the radius of convergence should be infinite (check p172 from Gamelin's _Complex Analysis_). However, If I expand around $z=4$, then the Laurent series of the denominator should be convergent at infinity and I will get terms of the form $1/(z-4)^k$.

Comment: I decide the radius of convergence based on the Corollary at page 146 of the reference I gave you.

Comment: Remember you want to compute the power series for the function, not for the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is an overkill, but the Weierstrass product for the cosine function gives
$$ \cos(z)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right) \tag{1} $$
hence
$$ \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2-\frac{\pi^2}{4}} = -\frac{4}{\pi^2}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}\right) \tag{2} $$
is an entire function and the RHS of $(2)$ is uniformly convergent over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$.